# Click a link inside a DIV with an external website?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I do have a simple website like this

> example.php

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <a id="myLink" href="http://example.com">Click!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I did load this website into a DIV-Container on a different site like this

> display.php

```
<div> 
    <object type="text/html" id="myFrame" data="example.php" width="800px" height="800px"></object>
</div>
```

Is there any way to click the link in example.php from the display.php via JQUERY without me having to change the example.php?

Comment: Clicking a link, does not need a **way**. Please try to edit your question and help everyone understand, what is your desired output

Comment: Why do you use `<object>` instead of `<iframe>` ?

Comment: The website EXAMPLE.PHP is loaded in a div-container in DISPLAY.PHP. I want a way to click the link via JQUERY for example. Not clicking by hand of course.

Comment: If you know a way that works with an iframe, i am listennig ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using an iframe instead of an object you can select its contents using jQuery like so:

```
$("iframe").contents().find("#myLink").click();
```

Comment: the `click()` does not fire click event. It just triggers when a `click` event happens

Comment: click() can simulate a click event. I use it all the time to do exactly that. Browsers are picky about what they'll let you do with iframes from external sites which could prevent it from working properly.

Comment: Exactly, it doesnt work anyways, i tried this one too, but thanks anyways

Comment: Assuming you can access the iframe's contents (depends on the iframe server's cross-origin policies and the browser), you could grab the href and set location.href yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fire the click event you may do it like this:

```
$('object').find('a').trigger('click');
```